# How do I compress folders (to .7z) and protect it with a password with encrypting files names (using a .bat file)?

Tags: 7zip

I want something like this:

for [Folder Name1] archive and password protect using this password (123456)

for [Folder Name2] archive and password protect using this password (789456)

for [Folder Name3] archive and password protect using this password (545gfdgf)

and so on…

I’m not technical so I only can copy the command, paste it in .txt, and then change the extension to .bat and run it.

I found this command but it’s not what I wanted:

for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.7z" "%%X" -mx=5 –tzip

Answer (score -1):

Maybe if you actually look at the manaul: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm

Comment: I did looked at the manual, but I'm really not into tech and I didn't understand what should I do :(

Comment: I think this site is for software developers who have run into a snag. Since you're not into tech you have just excluded yourself from being a software developer with a snag.  I would suggest you try freelancer.com or somewhere like that.  You could re-submit your question with different wording and you may be able to attract someones interest in your problem.